# Evaluating $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac {e^{-ax}}{ax+b} \, {\rm d} x$ in terms of $a$ and $b$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

How can I compute integrals of the following form

$$ \int_{x=0}^\infty \frac {e^{-ax}}{ax+b} \, {\rm d} x $$

where $a, b > 0$?

The first equation was actually  $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}k.e^{-(ax+by)}dxdy  = 1$$ Here I am trying to calculate joint probability of X and Y.
As a final step, question asks me to find k in terms of a and b. I just arrived to the equation above , but couldn't go any further.

By the way, the answer is k=ab

Comment: Maybe do $u=ax+b$? Then you have to integrate something like $\frac{\exp(-u)}u$.

Comment: Some context would be helpful (and without it, the question is likely to be closed). In any case the integral reduces to evaluating $\int \frac{e^{-u} \,du}{u}$, which has no closed form in elementary functions; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral.

Comment: the result must be in a and b form, and no other  extra information is given

Comment: @Utkarsh ,did you understand the answer?

Comment: Presumably, $a>0,b>0.$ If $a\leq 0,$ the function is bounded below by $\frac1{ax+b},$ where the integral does not converge, and if $b\leq 0,$ the function is undefined at $x=-b/a$ and you can only get some principal value for the integral.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ,under this condition, how can ı solve  that integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the easier way to solve this integral is by going back to the first equation you were given, as then we can use linearity of the integral to say
$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-ax-by}dxdy = \int_0^\infty e^{-by} \int_0^\infty e^{-ax} dx dy$$
Hopefully it is clear where to go from here!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes it is easy to go from here. But could you a bit explain the thing you did?What  does linearity of integration mean?

Comment: @ACrescendo $\int k\ f(x)\ dx = k \int f(x) \ dx$

Comment: Ahaha , ok, that does the trick. ı was away from math classes for a long time.Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

$k=ab$ and the Ei-inegral computation ($a>0$):
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ax}}{ax+b}\overset{u=ax+b}=\frac{e^b}{a}\int_b^{\infty}\frac{e^{-u}}{u}du=-\frac{e^b}{a}Ei(-b)$$

Ei: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral (Ramanujan had a lot of spare time to find a fast converging series in World War I.)